# Is there any open library to read/write csv/xls files in web api core?

Tags: csv, import, export, asp.net-core-webapi, xls

I want to automate some process, which is currently done by macro.
I want to read excel/csv file and perform some business logic and write the result back to csv. 
I want to achieve it through .net web api core. Are there any open source libraries like csvhelper, EPPlus.Core etc?

Please help me